# Chrome Extension to change innerText using Content Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to change the text of a h2 on a page using a Chrome extension using a content script I have the extension set up and I have a script.js file that is being loaded for my content script.

```
script.js

document.getElementById('texttochange').innerText = "CHANGED !";
```

However I am always getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
```

Is there something extra that needs to be done for Chrome Extensions, this works fine if loaded as a user.js userscript and letting Chrome install install it, this makes me think its a minifest issue however I do not know what I'm missing?

```
manifest.json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Test",
  "icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
             "48": "icon48.png",
             "128": "icon128.png" },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://example.com"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
}
```

---

I could not add a comment as my browser cache got cleared.

The structure is:

```
<frameset>
    <frame>
    ...
        <h2 id="texttochange">This should change</h2>
    ...
    </frame>
</frameset>
```

Here is the link te the extension, it is very simple, and in this case it is trying to change a `h2` on the site omegle.com which is using the frameset, frame thing from above.

Comment: Is "http://site.com" an example value for "matches"?

Comment: Is "texttochange" the ID of the h2 element?

Comment: yes to both, i did not need to put the real site as this is a very general question that can be applied to any site.

Comment: I have merged your 4 (!) accounts.  **Please register your account using a _real_ email address** to avoid these issues.

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("texttochange", "g"),"CHANGED !");
document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("texttochange", "g"),"CHANGED !");
```

and

```
{
"name": "My First Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "The first extension that I made.",
"background_page": "background.html",
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html" 
},
"permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/" ]
}
```

this is my manifest. The code I posted was in background.html and ran on chrome.tabs.onUpdated just in case the script part might be causing it to not work for some reason

Comment: nope that does nothing. if I use setInterval (which I will be eventually using to do other stuff) the page just keeps reloading.

Comment: Hm that should work it was copied straight from my extension.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this error because your script is injected before DOM load. So, the h2 element that you  are trying to change don't exist yet. Just add "run_at": "document_end" in your content_script section then it should work.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Test",
  "icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
             "48": "icon48.png",
             "128": "icon128.png" },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://site.com"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**script.js**

```
document.getElementById('h2Id').innerText = "CHANGED !";
```

Comment: I tried that, as well as using document_idle. neither worked, same as before.

Comment: So you are using an wrong id or it's inside a iframe. Take a look.